# find -exec {} + argument list limit

Tags: find, xargs, arguments

I know that when the maximum argument list size is reached, `xargs` keeps creating new lists until all of the files are included;

but does `find -exec <command> {} +` do the same thing or will it not work if the size of the list exceeds the output of `getconf ARG_MAX`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `find -exec ... {} +` runs the given command as many times as necessary to accommodate all the arguments without exceeding the maximum argument list size in each invocation. This is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> If the primary expression is punctuated by a <plus-sign>, the primary shall always evaluate as true, and the pathnames for which the primary is evaluated shall be aggregated into sets. [...] An argument containing only the two characters "`{}`" shall be replaced by the set of aggregated pathnames, with each pathname passed as a separate argument to the invoked utility in the same order that it was aggregated. **The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded.**

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 3):

It does the same thing, i.e. using `-exec ... {} +` will execute the given utility with batches of found pathnames, one or several times.  This is what this syntax is for.